# ngFor not displaying values in table over UI

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am trying to display the documents from my MongoDb collection over my Angular UI using MEAN STACK with Angular 4 (I am new to this technology)

Html code: Admin.component.html

```
 <div class="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>TrainingName</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
                        <td>{{ item.trainingName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
                        <td><button (click)="deleteitem(item._id)">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

typescript code: admin.component.ts

```
export class AdminFormComponent implements OnInit {
   private apiError= '';
   private items ='';

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.newSession = SessionDetails.CreateDefault();
     this.getFormdetails();
    }

getFormdetails()
{
  this.dataService
  .getUsers()
  .subscribe(
    details=>this.items= details,
    err => this.apiError = err
  )
}
}
```

dataservice:

```
getUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/all")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json());
    }
```

http://localhost:3000/all is returning the set of documents from mongo db collection.But I am unable to see the output over my angular UI.i.e. values for items are not getting displayed.

Comment: What do you see when you log details `.subscribe(=>console.log(detail),...` ? Maybe the server result is wrapped in a data field. You can also try to add `{{items|json}}` in your template.

Comment: I checked the value of details through console and it resulted in array with desired values into it.

Comment: And does `{{items|json}}` show something ?

Comment: Is the HTML inside a form tag, or is the same that you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

You initialize items as a string here.

```
private items ='';
```

Write instead

```
private items: any;
```

Comment: Its sill not displaying anything even after declaring items to any data type instead of string

Answer (score 0):

```
private items: any[]= [];
```

and can u try

```
let item of items; let i = index
```

Comment: I tried using the i = index in my html code. The values for the fields are not gettting displayed However, the index values are getting displayed in the table

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are getting data from the database using do like this. Also your items variable is not an array.

```
getUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .do(data => console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

Comment: I am getting the values from the database. 
I checked the value of details (in typescript code)  through console.log and it resulted in array with desired values into it.

Comment: make the iteams variable an array.